# How to change drawableTop image size

Tags: android

I have a button with drawableTop, is there any way to change the drawableTop image height and width, I can able to change the padding of drawableTop  but not height or width, any suggestions thanks in advance.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/inventory_Icon"
    android:text="Inventory"/>
```

Comment: have you tried my solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like below one.

```
Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(id);
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 30, 30);
yourTextView.setCompoundDrawables(drawable, null, null, null);
```

**Done**